# Using an Icon across user downloads

Tags: c++, windows, shortcut, ico, lnk

So I'm in the final stages of a project I've been working on. I went ahead and created an ICO file for my shortcut but now I'm not sure how to preserve the ICO file as the background.

When  I compress the file and send it to someone else, they open it but the shortcut doesn't work, since the shortcut links to a difference space inside their local storage. The ICO is also not preserved- presumably because it is stored locally.

My question is this- what is the best/fastest way to create a shortcut that is persistent across all users computers, without forcing them to make their own? In a perfect world an ICO file could be embedded in a link, but it doesn't look like that's possible. I have no idea how you would go about addressing the issue with the hard drive, since a user's file layout could be different from my own. It seems that this would have to be accomplished programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on what you mean by "preserve the ICO file as the background".

You could possibly add the ICO file as a resource in you C++ project.

How to add the ICO as a resource will depend on your C++ IDE.

When you create a shortcut to the application it should use the first ICO file it can find in the .exe file.

Comment: You'v'e got the gist of it. What I have in mind is that the user is able to create a shortcut that already has the background I've created without any extra hassle.